# SharePoint Search result not appearing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, sharepoint-search

Search result not appearing when i search the content in SharePoint list search and site level search.But I could see the crawled content in SharePoint crawled logs.I did reindex in SharePoint list settings in order to crawl again.But still issue remains same.

Answer (score 0):

I need to collect the following information to further troubleshoot the issue:

Is there some error message when you do the search?

Can you search other content in the same site?

Check whether other user can search the content.

Make sure the managed property is searchable. And the crawled property is Include in full-text index.

You can search with managed property like: Author:administrator, compare the results.

Comment: Please find below my answer.Is there some error message when you do the search?

Comment: I cannot see your answer.

Answer (score 0):

1 thing to take a look at also is permission setup, basically SharePoint search won't retrieve items that you don't have access to. Just some points to consider.

Hope the concept helps! Happy Learning!